# mlgradle doesn't create replica forests

Tags: replication, marklogic, ml-gradle

I read the examples about the creation of replicas, I do it last year, but the almost same properties file doesn't now create them on a new database.
My forests description are :

**mlForestsPerHost**=he-content,2,he-content-MEDIA,2,he-media-content-TRIGGERS,1,he-media-content-SCHEMAS,1,he-content-TRIGGERS,1,he-content-SCHEMAS,1,he-test-triggers,1,he-test-schemas,1,he-test-content,1

**mlDatabaseNamesAndReplicaCounts**=he-content,2,he-content-MEDIA,1,he-content-media-TRIGGERS,1,he-content-media-SCHEMAS,1,he-content-TRIGGERS,1,he-content-SCHEMAS,1,he-test-triggers,0,he-test-schemas,0,he-test-content,0

When I run a  mlPrintForestPlan task without any bases on my server, the JSON generated has the replicas description, but when I do a  mldeploydatabase I don't have the replicas created

from  **mlPrintForestPlan**

```
    {
  "forest-name" : "he-content-1",
  "host" : "ip-10-205-72-217.eu-west-1.compute.internal",
  "database" : "he-content",
  "forest-replica" : [ {
    "host" : "ip-10-205-73-136.eu-west-1.compute.internal",
    "replica-name" : "he-content-1-replica-1"
  }, {
    "host" : "ip-10-205-73-47.eu-west-1.compute.internal",
    "replica-name" : "he-content-1-replica-2"
  } ]
}
{
  "forest-name" : "he-content-2",
  "host" : "ip-10-205-72-217.eu-west-1.compute.internal",
  "database" : "he-content",
  "forest-replica" : [ {
    "host" : "ip-10-205-73-47.eu-west-1.compute.internal",
    "replica-name" : "he-content-2-replica-1"
  }, {
    "host" : "ip-10-205-73-136.eu-west-1.compute.internal",
    "replica-name" : "he-content-2-replica-2"
  } ]
}
{
  "forest-name" : "he-content-3",
  "host" : "ip-10-205-73-136.eu-west-1.compute.internal",
  "database" : "he-content",
  "forest-replica" : [ {
    "host" : "ip-10-205-73-47.eu-west-1.compute.internal",
    "replica-name" : "he-content-3-replica-1"
  }, {
    "host" : "ip-10-205-72-217.eu-west-1.compute.internal",
    "replica-name" : "he-content-3-replica-2"
  } ]
}
{
  "forest-name" : "he-content-4",
  "host" : "ip-10-205-73-136.eu-west-1.compute.internal",
  "database" : "he-content",
  "forest-replica" : [ {
    "host" : "ip-10-205-72-217.eu-west-1.compute.internal",
    "replica-name" : "he-content-4-replica-1"
  }, {
    "host" : "ip-10-205-73-47.eu-west-1.compute.internal",
    "replica-name" : "he-content-4-replica-2"
  } ]
}
{
  "forest-name" : "he-content-5",
  "host" : "ip-10-205-73-47.eu-west-1.compute.internal",
  "database" : "he-content",
  "forest-replica" : [ {
    "host" : "ip-10-205-72-217.eu-west-1.compute.internal",
    "replica-name" : "he-content-5-replica-1"
  }, {
    "host" : "ip-10-205-73-136.eu-west-1.compute.internal",
    "replica-name" : "he-content-5-replica-2"
  } ]
}
{
  "forest-name" : "he-content-6",
  "host" : "ip-10-205-73-47.eu-west-1.compute.internal",
  "database" : "he-content",
  "forest-replica" : [ {
    "host" : "ip-10-205-73-136.eu-west-1.compute.internal",
    "replica-name" : "he-content-6-replica-1"
  }, {
    "host" : "ip-10-205-72-217.eu-west-1.compute.internal",
    "replica-name" : "he-content-6-replica-2"
  } ]
}
```

from  **mldeploydatabase**

```
     {
      "forest-name" : "he-content-1",
      "host" : "ip-10-205-72-217.eu-west-1.compute.internal",
      "database" : "he-content"
    }, {
      "forest-name" : "he-content-2",
      "host" : "ip-10-205-72-217.eu-west-1.compute.internal",
      "database" : "he-content"
    }, {
      "forest-name" : "he-content-3",
      "host" : "ip-10-205-73-136.eu-west-1.compute.internal",
      "database" : "he-content"
    }, {
      "forest-name" : "he-content-4",
      "host" : "ip-10-205-73-136.eu-west-1.compute.internal",
      "database" : "he-content"
    }, {
      "forest-name" : "he-content-5",
      "host" : "ip-10-205-73-47.eu-west-1.compute.internal",
      "database" : "he-content"
    }, {
      "forest-name" : "he-content-6",
      "host" : "ip-10-205-73-47.eu-west-1.compute.internal",
      "database" : "he-content"
    }
```

I don't understand why

*mlgradle version 4.6.1*

Answer (score 0):

Given this note on the wiki:
https://github.com/marklogic/ml-gradle/wiki/Creating-forests#previewing-forest-creation

> This task will use all of the above configuration properties to determine what forests and replicas will be created when you run "mlDeploy" (or via a combination of "mlDeployDatabases" and "mlConfigureForestReplicas").

It would seem that you would want to run both `mlDeployDatabases` AND the `mlConfigureForestReplicas` tasks, or just run `mlDeploy`.

Comment: Wen I use any of this tasks, the result is the same, no replicas created. I have read this page before. I will retry it

Comment: I don't know why, but the mlDeploy doesn't create the replica, but perhaps because it does it after the modules where I have a access port error when I deploy the services on the application port and not the 8000 (an other problem that i have to solve). The both task successfully are ok, thank you I don't read the "AND".

Comment: What error do you get when loading modules via your application port? That sometimes happens when SSL is required by either 8000 or your application port and there's a misconfiguration such that modules are loaded via 8000 successfully but not via the application port.